# Having trouble syncing testnet post HF

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, testnets

I'm having issues syncing my geth node to the Morden testnet after the recent protocol change.

Everything was working fine on Monday - today I downloaded geth-1.4.18 and attempted to sync but any time I launched geth syncing would start then I would receive a Bad block error followed by a gas used error after which geth appeared to become stuck.

I've renamed my testnet directory and I'm currently in the process of redownloading the entire testnet chain from scratch (not using --fast) however I'm worried about what I should do in the event that this also becomes stuck.

Anything I should try to be able to sync with my old testnet chaindata?

Comment: Did you fix it?  I was doing a fast synch with Morden and got the following error:

Bad block #1790179 (0x250657d03e0f6d6e0c148b4063abc03a341745754acfae5c126060b833bcbc5f)
E1019 23:36:40.107305 core/blockchain.go:1190]     gas used error (129116 / 130916)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may have downloaded part of the testnet blockchain after the testnet gas reprice hard fork at block [1,783,000](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/c72f5459ac110de47fa068bfa560164078508b1e#diff-a3b66a5682ce7850e57bbd3de0087274R24).

If this had occurred, your old chain data is incompatible with the new client as mentioned in [FAQ: Upcoming Ethereum Hard Fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/):

> **What happens if I do not participate in the hard fork?**
>
> If you are using an Ethereum client that is not updated for the upcoming hard fork, your client will sync to the pre-fork blockchain once the fork occurs. You will be stuck on an incompatible chain following the old rules and you will be unable to send ether or operate on the post-fork Ethereum network.

You then have to re-sync the blockchain from scratch.

Comment: I also get the following error after starting a new fast --testnet sync:  

Bad block #1790179 (0x250657d03e0f6d6e0c148b4063abc03a341745754acfae5c126060b833bcbc5f)
E1019 23:36:40.107305 core/blockchain.go:1190]     gas used error (129116 / 130916)